# allure in my jenkins takes huge amount of time to finish the last step

Tags: jenkins, allure

I don't know if anyone has the save issue. I have a jenkins service running on my ubuntu, in which there is job "FEXT-DAILY" to execute some selenium cases. When this job is triggered, it is to generate the allure report at the end.  What I have noticed is, it always takes huge amount of time to have this step finished. As you may see from the console output from the current session, it keeps circling circling for at least 20+ minutes to have it done, even if a light-weight selenium case was executed.

[image]

Any idea how to make it better ? my allure is of version 2.7.0 on ubuntu.

Thanks,

Chun

Comment: It looks like the allure report step is finished and it is pending on `Creating artifact for the build.` What's the size of the artifacts your are packing?

Comment: I do have some screenshot in the report, but I didn't expect such long time to have it generated.